# Mysql connection after release in node.js + mysql pool

Tags: mysql, node.js, pool

I cannot understand why could I connect to Mysql after release.

And is there a way to check the status of Mysql ?

Thanks for the help !

```
var mysqlConfig = {
    host     : "abcd",
    port     : "3306",
    user     : "root",
    password : "root",
    database : "test"
};
var pool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);


pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    // release pool
    conn.release();

    // After release, Why could I connect to Mysql ????
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = ?', [id], function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            pushErr();
        }
        // ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation here: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql it looks like the connection being 'released' doesn't destroy the connection per se, it just signals the pool that it can be used by someone else if needed.  If you notice the example, they release as part of the query callback.  If you need to actually get rid of the connection,  you should use `conn.destroy()`.